# Passing JSON data from Angular component to Electron main.ts

Tags: angular, electron

As title says, I'm working on an Angular 9 app which utilizes electron for packaging and some Node functionality.

I'm trying to send some data from one of my components to Electron's main process so I can utilize Node's filesystem, but I'm having troubles receiving said data.

here's a (rough) example of what I want to achieve:

```
// on form.ts, should prepare the object and send it away
private ipc: IpcRenderer;
submit() {
  const json = {...json data...}
  this.ipc.send('save', json);
}

// on main.js, should receive and be able to print the object
ipcMain.on('save', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The function is called successfully, but I'm not having any luck passing the JSON object to it.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of the listener is the event, the second one the data. Try this:

```
ipcMain.on('save', (event, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```